# HTML: The best way to using template in big website

Tags: html

I am going to write a big website, it has hundreds of HTML pages. There are some parts of the file using the same HTML code, such as the banner, the bottom disclaimer, etc.
I want to update the common parts of the HTML in a batch when that parts are modified, I am seeking a way to efficiently do that.
Currently my solution is surround the tempates with HTML comments, and use Linux script(sed mainly) to update it when necessary. Like:

```
<!-- Template1 -->
<!-- Template1-end -->
```

Any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) is your friend. If you are building using a shell script that spits out static files (and it sounds like you are), then you'll want the [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) utility. You'll probably find [the tutorial](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) useful and want to make use of the [WRAPPER directive](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WRAPPER) (which lets you have a complete page with "Insert content here" sections rather then having to stick "Include header", "Include nav", "Include footer" in every content page).

Going with TT gives you the flexibility to move to server side scripting in the future with a minimum of effort (so long as you are happy using Perl for the server side programming) as Template-Toolkit has Perl modules as well as ttree.

Comment: TT looks fantastic, but I couldn't find many resources to help me with a really simple problem - I was unable to get an INCLUDE directive to work (on Windows). tpage couldn't see the .tt files the INCLUDE asked for, and I couldn't find a resource explaining how it actually looked for the included templates. I did try [the documentation](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_INCLUDE) but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). Either build a lightweight one or rely on an [existing one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems).

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to include templates, or just go the server side way and use dynamic page include methods, found by default in most appropriate web scripting languages. **There's no way to dynamically achieve this using HTML only**, you would have to go via a third party software or application to update your source files in the end anyway (like you already are doing with your  batch script).

Comment: Using client-side Javascript to include templates is a bad idea in most cases.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my friend :-) Doing this kind of project without a server side language is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: actually I hate the design of "server side language", I like using static pages with AJAX to get the data and display it on the webpage. That is clean isolation of client/server and data/view.